# how to do tls renegotiation by python ssl socket

Tags: python, ssl, handshake

I need to simulate a tls renegotiation behaviour (I understand this as a new handshake) by python. Is that possible?

I tried below codes, the first do_handshake works but the second one do nothing.

```
import socket, ssl, pprint, re, time
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s,ca_certs="cacert.pem",do_handshake_on_connect=False)

ssl_sock.connect(('172.18.7.162', 443))
time.sleep(3)
ssl_sock.do_handshake()
print repr(ssl_sock.getpeername())
print ssl_sock.cipher()
print pprint.pformat(ssl_sock.getpeercert())

send_content="aaaa"
ssl_sock.write(send_content)
time.sleep(2)
print "do_handshake_again"
ssl_sock.do_handshake()
print "do_handshake_again done"

ssl_sock.write(send_content)
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Why do you want to send two handshakes?

Comment: I need to simulate a behaviour: one packet include both handshake and application date.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question: 
Finally I implement this behaviour by using python openssl lib.

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
import sys, os, select, socket
........
# Initialize context
ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
ctx.set_options(SSL.OP_NO_SSLv2)

#ctx.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_PEER|SSL.VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, verify_cb) # Demand a certificate
ctx.use_privatekey_file (os.path.join(dir, 'server.pkey'))
ctx.use_certificate_file(os.path.join(dir, 'server.cert'))
ctx.load_verify_locations(os.path.join(dir, 'CA.cert'))

# Set up server
server = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
server.bind(('', int(sys.argv[1])))
server.listen(3)
server.setblocking(0)

........

    for cli in w:
        try:
            ret = cli.send(writers[cli])
            cli.renegotiate()      
            cli.do_handshake()
            ret = cli.send(writers[cli])
......
```

The important thing is the last 4 lines: 
1, sending something with the socket
2-3, trigger renegotiate and do handshake 
4, sending something again

Because it's non-blocking socket, I can see this code send out two packets: the first packet will only send application data(content type 23), the second packet will have two payloads: one is ssl handshake(type 22) and another one is application data(type 23).

By the way, this is trying to simulate re-negotiate packet has application data in same packet. If for pure tls re-negotiate, we can use openssl to send "R" to trigger a pure tls renegotiation behaviour.